# In pandas, how do I convert a series of float or none to strings with integers

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, type-conversion

I'm stuck with a pandas series that's containing document numbers but have been imported as float64 values. Some are missing.

Converting the series to string adds a ".0" to each number or changes the 
number to e-notation.

Converting to integer causes an error message:
*ValueError: Cannot convert NA to integer*

Example:

```
s = pd.Series([129944444999999922.0, 1001.0, 1119999999912.0, None])
s.astype('str')
```

prints

```
0       1.29944445e+17
1               1001.0
2    1.11999999991e+12
3                  nan
dtype: object
```

How can I convert the series to show the document number as just the number,
no e+ notation and the nan value as an empty string?

Comment: Do you really have document numbers as long as `129944444999999922`? If so, you'll have to change how they're being read-- otherwise you'll lose the last few digits.  (Compare that number with the first result of jezrael's answer.)

Comment: @DSM almost that length and enough to switch to e+ notation. I'm aware of potential rounding problems.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `list comprehension`:

```
s1 = pd.Series(['' if pd.isnull(x) else int(x) for x in s], index=s.index)

print (s1.apply(type))
0    <class 'int'>
1    <class 'int'>
2    <class 'int'>
3    <class 'str'>
dtype: object

print (s1.tolist())
[129944444999999920, 1001, 1119999999912, '']
```

Comment: Thanks. Alas, my example wasn't using long enough floats to break the numbers, so I changed that. Is that fixable, too?

Comment: @576i - I agree, so new solution was added.